# How to implement Foulke's algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math, matrix

Foulke's algorithm is defined by

```
(In + U)2 = In+ U + U2
```

with:

`In` : the identity matrix
`U` : square adjacent matrix

I want to implement this algorithm in C by recurrence.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And this is tagged C++ because...?

Comment: We'd love to help. What have you tried?

Comment: What does the 2 mean? Do you mean "^2" (squared)?

Comment: Should there be a two in front of `U` on the right side of the equation?

Comment: This isn't an algorithm; this is an equation.  Can you provide a useful link?

Comment: Is it really _Foulkes' Algorithm_?  The difference is in the location of the apostrophe, so in your spelling, the inventor's surname was 'Foulke' and in the alternative the surname was 'Foulkes'.  The latter seems to give better results in a Google search.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is wrong. Substitute `U` with identity matrix and you will see that the equality does not hold. You need to change it to `(In + U)^2 = In+ 2*U + U^2`. Just like numbers. Makes sense, huh?

Otherwise all you need to do is to implement a function that multiplies to two-dimensional matrices and returns the result in a two-dimensional array. I don't think using recursion for this problem is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use BLAS library. Or you want to make all yourself without any algebra-library?

Comment: Your answer would be improved by a link to the [BLAS](http://netlib.org/blas) library.  I know it doesn't take a lot of effort to find it, but it is best if people don't have to look.